# Does KinectChangedEventArgs.OldSensor mean Kinect for XBox and KinectChangedEventArgs.NewSensor mean Kinect for Windows?

Tags: kinect

I am trying to figure out what is KinectChangedEventArgs.OldSensor and KinectChangedEventArgs.NewSensor.  I looked into MSDN, but it does not give much information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.kinectchangedeventargs_properties.aspx

If KinectChangedEventArgs.OldSensor is not null, does that mean the kinect you are using is kinect for xbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This property is used in case you plug/unplug your kinect while the application is on or also if you have multiple Kinect plugged in the same time.

[Here's a pretty clear link](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2013/03/25/kinect-interactions-with-wpf-part-i-getting-started.aspx)